# Most efficient way to order by and update a row in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using this code to rank players in a game.

```
    private void RecalculateUserRanks(GWDatabase db)
    {
        // RankedScore is a precalculated Double.
        var users = db.UserStatistics.Where(x => x.RankedScore > 0);
        var usersWithRank = users.OrderByDescending(x => x.RankedScore)
               .Select(x => new
               {
                    x.Id,
                    x.RankedScore
               });

        int position = 0;
        foreach (var u in usersWithRank)
        {
            position++;
            db.UserStatistics.First(x => x.Id == u.Id).Rank = position;
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

It's not the prettiest and as the number of players grows this will probably take some time and use a bit of memory.

I could do this in pure TSQL like this:

```
;WITH r AS
  (
    SELECT 
        [Id]
        ,[RankedScore]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [RankedScore] DESC) AS Rnk
    FROM [dbo].[UsersStatistics]
)
UPDATE u
    SET u.Rank = r.Rnk
FROM [dbo].[UsersStatistics] u
INNER JOIN r ON r.Id = u.Id
```

But I would prefer to keep all my logic in the C# code as the database gets rebuilt all the time right now (and all other logic is there as well).

So my question is if there is a smarter way to do this in C# LINQ (or Lambda if thats your thing) without iterating over it in a for loop, and without dragging all the data outside of the SQL?

Comment: LINQ doesn't have any equivalent to windowing functions, so you're not going to accomplish it as elegantly as the SQL.

Comment: Are there any ways around dragging all the data out from the SQL?

Comment: Any reason you can't create a stored procedure in the database? Have a trigger that will adjust all of the other RankedScore values?

Comment: I don't think so because of the windowing functions. If you're against stored procedures because of database refreshes, you could always make it inline dynamic SQL in C#. It's not ideal I agree, but I don't know of a better way if you can't make a stored procedure.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to store **Rank** in the database rather than just working it out dynamically when you need it? Storing it means you need to shift your data every time a **RankedScore** changes

Comment: @timothyclifford Valid point, but I am thinking that recalculating the rank for every request with a couple of thousand users is going to be cumbersome. Better to do it once every 5 minutes for everyone and just give them the precalculated value.

Comment: @dman2306 I will probably do it that way if I cant make it more efficient in C#.

Answer (score 1):

I assume by 'efficient' you mean 'efficient to read'. For a faster calculation you might consider to use a sorted list for `db.UserStatistics`; Those keep themselves sorted, while using `log n` time to insert a new member.

This is pretty much the same you posted, except lazy-evaluation might save a little time:

```
//get sorted list of IDs
var SortedIds = db.UserStatistics
 .OrderByDescending(x => x.RankedScore)
 .Select(x => x.Id);

//Fill in Values into result-set
db.UserStatistics = db.UserStatistics
 .Where(x => x.RankedScore > 0)
 .ForEach(x => u.Rank = SortedIds.IndexOf(x.id));
```

It seems a little inconsistent to have ranked and unranked players together.

This will give unranked players the rank -1 while saving a step. The downside would be, that all user will be altered, instead just those with a rank:

```
db.UserStatistics = db.UserStatistics.ForEach(u => 
   u.Rank = db.UserStatistics
    .Where(x => x.RankedScore > 0)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.RankedScore)
    .IndexOf(u.id));
```

Comment: ´seems a little inconsistent to have ranked and unranked´ All players are ranked, but not untill they play atleast 3 games. So the only unranked players are the brand new ones that havent played any rounds yet.

Comment: Your code does look prettier than my C# code so I might use this for now. I will however probably need to do a inline dynamic SQL query from C# later on to get the performance I want.